# validation msg not working properly after removing value in angular. what is the right way?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on angular validation it was throwing validation on the page load itself which I don't want and also if I enter the value the validation msg disappears but if I go back into the textbox and delete the input it isn't throwing validation back. Please let me know what changes should I have to change to make it work

```
          <div class="row">
           <div class="input" style="margin-left:0px;">
            First Name
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="licenseInvite.FirstName" name="firstName" (ngModelChange)="update()" />
            <span *ngIf="isInValidFirstName()" class="validation error">Please provide first name</span>
            
        </div>
        <div class="input" style="margin-left:0px;">
            Last Name
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="licenseInvite.LastName" name="lastName" (ngModelChange)="update()" />
            <span *ngIf="isInValidLastName()" class="validation error">Please provide last name</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="input" style="margin-left:0px;">
            Email Address
            <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="licenseInvite.Email" name="email" (ngModelChange)="update()"
                [attr.disabled]="editEmail==false ? 'disabled' : null" />
            <span *ngIf="isInValid() && !isValidEmail()" class="validation error">Please provide a valid email address
            </span>
        </div>
```

---

```
    public isValidEmail(): boolean
    {
    const regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    
    const isValidEmail = regex.test(this.licenseInvite.Email);
    // TODO: If member select...
    return isValidEmail;
}

public isInValid():boolean {
    const hasAllFields = this.licenseInvite.Email == null &&
                         this.licenseInvite.Role == null &&
                         this.licenseInvite.CountryCode == null;
        return hasAllFields;
}

public isInValidFirstName(): boolean
{
    return this.licenseInvite.FirstName == null
}
public isInValidLastName(): boolean
{
    return this.licenseInvite.LastName == null
}

public isValid():boolean
{
   return !this.isInValidFirstName && !this.isInValidLastName && !this.isInValid
}


public update(): void {
    this.validLicenseInvite = this.isValid() ? this.licenseInvite : undefined;
    }
```

Comment: I wrote below and it worked but if I do negative testing by removing the value after entering it isn't display msg 
        <div class="input" style="margin-left:0px;">
                Email Address
                <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="licenseInvite.Email" name="email" #em="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="update()"
                    [attr.disabled]="editEmail==false ? 'disabled' : null" />
                <span *ngIf="!isValid() && !isValidEmail() && (em.dirty || em.touched)" class="validation error">Please provide a valid email address
                </span>
            </div>

Answer (score 0):

you can use dirty and touched property e.g.

`<span *ngIf="isInValid() && !isValidEmail() && (email.dirty || email.touched)"    class="validation error">`

for more info pls Refer to https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: yes already tried,

getting error in console like this

core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dirty')
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (FamisUpsertUserModalComponent.ngfactory.js:685:78)
    at Object.updateDirectives (core.js:23654:55)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307:1)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548:1)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490:1)
    at Object.checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313:1)
    at ViewRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.j
    at Array.forEach

Comment: I did this and it worked but if I do negative testing by removing the value after entering it isn't display msg 
        <div class="input" style="margin-left:0px;">
                Email Address
                <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="licenseInvite.Email" name="email" #em="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="update()"
                    [attr.disabled]="editEmail==false ? 'disabled' : null" />
                <span *ngIf="!isValid() && !isValidEmail() && (em.dirty || em.touched)" class="validation error">Please provide a valid email address
                </span>
            </div>